# Shouldn't the FAQ also suggest StackOverflow?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed

The [FAQ](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/faq) states:

> **What kind of questions should I not ask here?**
>
> [...]
>
> If your question is about …
>
> - Networking, servers, or maintaining other people's PCs and contains no source code, ask on Server Fault.
> - General computer software or hardware troubleshooting, ask on Super User.
> - Web design and HTML/CSS layout, and your job title is "designer", ask on Doctype.

How about adding something like:

- Programming functionality on your site, ask on StackOverflow

I'm concerned that we're diluting that key resource by not encouraging programming related questions on there.

Comment: nah, its not like Stackoverflow is important or popular or the grandaddy of this whole thing. I say we leave it out ;) +1

Comment: They really need to add something about stack overflow and move all of the programming questions to Stack overflow.  There are a ton of programming questions on the site already that really need to be moved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ah, excellent point -- added.

Comment: As a point of note, shouldn't the AppOffline file be more stack exchange based on here, rather than telling me, lots of times, with a lot of highlights that StackOverflow is down for maintenance?

Comment: In general, per Jeff's answer about what is listed for migrating questions between sites, I'd think the same sites would appear in the FAQ:  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52141/will-it-be-possible-to-migrate-questions-between-the-trilogy-and-the-stack-exchan/54524#54524

Comment: I was just about to ask this same question hoping others could avoid the issues I was having,.. where is this in the webmaster's FAQ o_O?

Comment: @garet this is automated now based on the open "blessed" question migration routes. I'll make sure the webmasters -> SO route is blessed

Comment: @garet it's already in there -- "If your question would be of interest to … Professional and enthusiast programmers, ask on Stack Overflow." because that is already a blessed close reason here on Pro Webmasters

Comment: absolutely no idea how i missed it.

Answer (score 2):

I think the FAQ should list all the stack exchange websites even remotely similar.